# MySQL Leaderboard query optimization

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

I'm currently making a leaderboard where I'm using the specific code to go:

```java
public long checkPosition(String table,String column, UUID uuid){
        DataAPI dataAPI = Core.getInstance().getDataAPI();

        String index = table + "_index_" + column;


        //SELECT id, name, score, FIND_IN_SET( score, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY score DESC ) FROM scores )) AS rank FROM scores WHERE name =  'Assem'
        //SELECT 1 + COUNT(*) AS rank FROM table WHERE "+column+" > (SELECT "+column+" FROM "+table+" WHERE uuid='"+uuid.toString()+"')

        int level = 300;

        String query = "SELECT 1 + COUNT(*) AS rank FROM "+table+" FORCE INDEX("+index+") WHERE "+column+" > (SELECT `"+column+"` FROM week_statistics_users FORCE INDEX(week_statistics_users_index_uuid) WHERE `uuid`='"+uuid.toString()+"');";

        try (Connection connection = dataAPI.getConnection()
             ;PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)){
            ResultSet resultSet;
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            resultSet.next();
            return (long) resultSet.getObject(1);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

You can see I am trying to force an index usage, I am trying to optimize that query, in a table of 1M user its taking 2 seconds - per query.

I don't know exactly why its taking all that, I can tell you the index is multi column, always the uuid, and the column string, all of the colums are BIGINTs, is there anyway I can optimize that query? am I making any mistake with the index? maybe I am not using it correctly, or maybe the issue is in the SELECT COUNT(*).

```
MariaDB [s2_goliath]> EXPLAIN SELECT 1 + COUNT(*) AS rank FROM lifetime_statistics_users WHERE kills > (SELECT kills FROM week_statistics_users WHERE uuid='2bd9d043-8187-444c-8536-ebd843885ad2');
+------+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table                     | type  | possible_keys                                                                   | key                                   | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | lifetime_statistics_users | range | lifetime_statistics_users_index_kills,lifetime_statistics_users_index_killsuuid | lifetime_statistics_users_index_kills | 9       | NULL  | 118320 | Using where; Using index |
|    2 | SUBQUERY    | week_statistics_users     | const | PRIMARY,week_statistics_users_index_uuid                                        | PRIMARY                               | 402     | const | 1      |                          |
+------+-------------+---------------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Update:

SHOW TABLE STATUS:

````java
| Name                      | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment | Max_index_length | Temporary

| month_statistics_users    | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 248956 |            200 |    50020352 |               0 |    392118272 |   6291456 |           NULL | 2022-07-30 17:28:22 | 2022-07-31 16:53:50 | NULL       | utf8mb4_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |                0 | N        

```

SHOW CREATE TABLE:
```java

MariaDB [s2_goliath]> SHOW CREATE TABLE lifetime_statistics_users \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: lifetime_statistics_users
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `lifetime_statistics_users` (
  `uuid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `json` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `kills` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deaths` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `playtime` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `money` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `texture` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `blocks_broken` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `blocks_placed` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobs_killed` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_uuid` (`uuid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_name` (`name`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_nameuuid` (`name`,`uuid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_kills` (`kills`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_killsuuid` (`kills`,`uuid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_deaths` (`deaths`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_deathsuuid` (`deaths`,`uuid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_playtime` (`playtime`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_playtimeuuid` (`playtime`,`uuid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_money` (`money`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_moneyuuid` (`money`,`uuid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_level` (`level`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_blocks_broken` (`blocks_broken`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_blocks_brokenuuid` (`blocks_broken`,`uuid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_blocks_placed` (`blocks_placed`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_blocks_placeduuid` (`blocks_placed`,`uuid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_mobs_killed` (`mobs_killed`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lifetime_statistics_users_index_mobs_killeduuid` (`mobs_killed`,`uuid`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```
````

Comment: Please share your table schemas, their indexes, the result of [`explain ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html), and what the query is doing.

Comment: Hey @Schwern my table schema is really simple, each table contains column and a uuid as primary key. The indexes are based on uuid and column, i reffer column to some which can be level, playtime, they're all BIGINT.

The query should be calculating the amount of users that have the "column" higher than the user with the provided uuid, its basically RANKING the position of the user based on the database data.

Comment: @Schwern I've added the explain!

Comment: The query in your image and the query in your question do not match, they do completely different things. How long does that query in your explain take (it looks fine). Also please add the output of "show create table tablename" (which is what Schwern meant) including the indexes, so we can check if they do what you assume they do.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconsistency in the query I was using, I changed it since the other one wasn't really working, I've posted the show create table! -> I would say to ignore the indexes that endup with uuid, I was just testing them to see if there would be any benefit using it with both columns at the same time, but I didn't see any.

Comment: @Solarflare, would you be able to see if indexes are doing what I am assuming they're doing?

Comment: Please add the information as text, not as images. Your execution plan looks correct though. As a sanity check, could you test a high level player? The runtime should be very fast, while a level 0 player will require all rows to be read. Also, for comparison, do a `select count(*) from tablename` (e.g. just the number of rows). It should be as slow as the lowest rank player.

Comment: @Solarflare I understand about the reading all the table, what I don't understand is: In the analyze it shows that the query takes 16ms, while in my java application, its taking 80ms if I don't run the analyze on the sql server directly, for an example: all columns were taking around 80ms to rank the user, while the ones I analyzed the query execution, started taking 16ms(these are money, playtime, and level), and if I run the analyze again, but in other columns, they start taking the same amount of time, why is that?

Comment: That example is actually with 100k users on the database(which isn't really that much), and my level is 0, while all the other users have random levels but they're high numbers!
Why does the "Analyze" speed up the query somehow?

Comment: 1) Note that almost all of your single column indexes are redundant. `(name)` is redundant with `(name, uuid)` for example. The only single column index you need is `(uuid)`. See [Multiple-column indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html). 2) As for the differing times between a direct query (16ms) and in the Java code (80ms), how are you measuring the times? You might just be measuring network latency and Java overhead. 3) Try removing `force index`. You shouldn't need it for such simple queries; let the optimizer figure it out.

Comment: @Schwern I'm mainly measuring the time of the response based on the System millis, and even if there were issues with the code, the response changes after running the analyzer. the 16ms is told by the mysql server in analyze, after that, when running the query again in my java app, it does match with the sql server time response somehow.

Comment: If the query is slow the first time and faster the second, that could be just disk caching. The first query has to read the data from disk, which is slow, after that it's in memory, which is fast.

Comment: Please provide the query _after_ it is put together.  That is, after substituting "column", etc and concatenating it all.

Comment: @Schwern It's not disk, that's what I am saying, i am running that query a 100 times in the java app and the responses are close to 80ms always, but when I go ahead in my ssh panel and run the ANALYZE on MariaDB, it suddenly starts performing better and the query goes to close to 16ms, that's what I mean.

Comment: @RickJamesa 
SELECT 1 + COUNT(*) AS rank FROM lifetime_statistics_users WHERE kills > (SELECT `kills` FROM week_statistics_users WHERE `uuid`='2bd9d043-8187-444c-8536-ebd843885ad2');

Comment: @PedroPauloMontePagani - 80ms vs 16ms -- Are the database, Java, and ssh panel all on the same server?  Or is there a latency issue?

Comment: Hey @RickJames, no there is no latency issue, they're not in the same node but still, the request isn't requesting too much data from the sql server, so there wouldn't be a reason for a latency issue.

Comment: "Latency" is about how long it takes to get to the server; "throughput" is about how much can be shoveled per second.  How long does "SELECT 1" take?  That will be the "latency".

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Comment: @RickJames the system millis between the query starting the execution and getting out of the block of executeQuery (which is basically once the sql finishes processing and returns the response), is the 80ms, latency between dedis is 1ms local, specially with a query carrying a low response like that(in terms of bytes) 
The 80ms is consistent sometimes, if I run the queries EXPLAIN or ANALYZE, it mostly goes down to 16ms in the java application itself too, that's why its "weird".

Comment: Let me approach from another direction.  How much RAM on the database server?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How big (in GB) is the data?  (`SHOW TABLE STATUS` or look on the disk.)  `SHOW CREATE TABLE lifetime_statistic_users \G` -- the `\G` avoids the long line of dashes.

Comment: @RickJames I just looked at the innnodb buffer pool, and I couldn't find an option, so I figured it would be 10MB since thats what the file located at /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf said. Is that correct?
I uncommented it and restarted my mariadb server, with the option on 8G.
Also would like to point out that after increasing the innodb buffer size the latency response (everything summed up together, mysql query run + latency) close to 35ms!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `FORCE INDEX` clauses.  That is causing the slowdown.

After that, show us the `EXPLAIN` again, but in text *not* as an essentially unreadable image.

(I don't have an answer to the 80ms vs 16ms)

**More**

That query is counting how many rows have `kills > ...` and coming up with 118K.  This takes time.  It cannot be speeded up.  But you could  change to percentile, then have a simple table of them.

Here's a thought...  Keep the high-scorers doing the current COUNT, but limit that to users with more than X kills.  X = somewhere around the 10th percentile.  Then have a table of 100 percentiles that is periodically updated.  That is, it is done in the background, not at the time when you are showing the user his ranking.  That tiny table would have the number of kills for each of the 100 percentiles; the query would be a very fast index lookup, something:

```
SELECT ptile
    FROM week_ptiles
       WHERE ( SELECT kills FROM week_statistics_users
                  WHERE uuid='...'
             ) >= kills LIMIT 1;

CREATE TABLE week_ptiles (
    ptile TINYINT NOT NULL,
    kills BIGINT NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(ptile),
    INDEX(kills, ptile)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I've already removed the FORCE INDEX clauses and it's still the same response, 80ms for a 100k user table, and close to 200ms for a 234k user table. I've put the text of explain in the main thread, sorry!

Comment: @PedroPauloMontePagani - Can't fix your problem _as it stands_.  I provide a variation that involves a UI change.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your help, I implemented a caching application that recalculates the player position from time to time in the database (Specifically because your usggestion made the query faster), your suggestion on the buffer pool size helped a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @PedroPauloMontePagani - Also check out Redis's ZSET.